# "ilc.exe" exit code 1104 when compiling in "Release" mode

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, build, uwp

I'm getting only this error (1104) when I build my UWP app in "Release" mode (only in x86) so I can't create app packages...In debug and Release (x64) modes works perfectly. 
Any idea of what's causing this issue and how can I solve it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, problem solved. I took the following steps:

1. Clean solution
2. Delete "bin" and "obj" directories completely
3. Recompile and run the app without problem

Regards and "thanks" for the downvote...